# Tensorflow lite model(.tflite) in android is always giving the same result for text classification

Tags: java, python, android, android-studio, tensorflow

I am trying to classify the messages that i receive into 5 categories(sports, politics, business, tech, entertainment), but for every message I send the tflite model classify it as sports ONLY.
this is my model:
i am using Average Word Vector model to train and test my data. and it gives me correct predictions when testing it. However, when I integrate the model into android studio, the model always predict the message as sports with high accuracy(around 95%)

```
!pip install -q tflite-model-maker

import numpy as np
import os
from tflite_model_maker import configs
from tflite_model_maker import ExportFormat
from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
from tflite_model_maker import text_classifier
from tflite_model_maker import TextClassifierDataLoader
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

data = pd.read_csv("bbc-text.csv")
print(data)

awv_spec = model_spec.get('average_word_vec')

awv_train_data = TextClassifierDataLoader.from_csv(
    filename='bbc-text.csv',
    text_column='text',
    label_column='category',
    model_spec=awv_spec,
    is_training=True)
awv_test_data = TextClassifierDataLoader.from_csv(
    filename='bbc-text1.csv',
    text_column='text',
    label_column='category',
    model_spec=awv_spec,
    is_training=False)

awv_model = text_classifier.create(awv_train_data, model_spec=awv_spec, epochs=20)

awv_model.evaluate(awv_test_data)

awv_model.export(export_dir='average_word_vec/')
```

and this is how i retrive info in android:

```
package com.example.letstalk.lib_interpreter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.letstalk.lib_interpreter.Result;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.metadata.MetadataExtractor;

public class TextClassificationClient {
private static final String TAG = "Interpreter";

private static final int SENTENCE_LEN = 256; // The maximum length of an input sentence.
// Simple delimiter to split words.
private static final String SIMPLE_SPACE_OR_PUNCTUATION = " |\\,|\\.|\\!|\\?|\n";
private static final String MODEL_PATH = "sentiment_analysis.tflite";
/*
 * Reserved values in ImdbDataSet dic:
 * dic["<PAD>"] = 0      used for padding
 * dic["<START>"] = 1    mark for the start of a sentence
 * dic["<UNKNOWN>"] = 2  mark for unknown words (OOV)
 */
private static final String START = "<START>";
private static final String PAD = "<PAD>";
private static final String UNKNOWN = "<UNKNOWN>";

/** Number of results to show in the UI. */
private static final int MAX_RESULTS = 3;

private final Context context;
private final Map<String, Integer> dic = new HashMap<>();
private final List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
private Interpreter tflite;

public TextClassificationClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

/** Load the TF Lite model and dictionary so that the client can start classifying text. */
public void load() {
    loadModel();
}

/** Load TF Lite model. */
private synchronized void loadModel() {
    try {
        // Load the TF Lite model
        ByteBuffer buffer = loadModelFile(this.context.getAssets(), MODEL_PATH);
        tflite = new Interpreter(buffer);
        Log.v(TAG, "TFLite model loaded.");

        // Use metadata extractor to extract the dictionary and label files.
        MetadataExtractor metadataExtractor = new MetadataExtractor(buffer);

        // Extract and load the dictionary file.
        InputStream dictionaryFile = metadataExtractor.getAssociatedFile("vocab.txt");
        loadDictionaryFile(dictionaryFile);
        Log.v(TAG, "Dictionary loaded.");

        // Extract and load the label file.
        InputStream labelFile = metadataExtractor.getAssociatedFile("labels.txt");
        loadLabelFile(labelFile);
        Log.v(TAG, "Labels loaded.");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading TF Lite model.\n", ex);
    }
}

/** Free up resources as the client is no longer needed. */
public synchronized void unload() {
    tflite.close();
    dic.clear();
    labels.clear();
}

/** Classify an input string and returns the classification results. */
public synchronized List<Result> classify(String text) {
    // Pre-prosessing.
    int[][] input = tokenizeInputText(text);

    // Run inference.
    Log.v(TAG, "Classifying text with TF Lite...");
    float[][] output = new float[1][labels.size()];
    tflite.run(input, output);

    // Find the best classifications.
    PriorityQueue<Result> pq =
            new PriorityQueue<>(
                    MAX_RESULTS, (lhs, rhs) -> Float.compare(rhs.getConfidence(), lhs.getConfidence()));
    for (int i = 0; i < labels.size(); i++) {
        pq.add(new Result("" + i, labels.get(i), output[0][i]));
    }
    final ArrayList<Result> results = new ArrayList<>();
    while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
        results.add(pq.poll());
    }

    Collections.sort(results);
    // Return the probability of each class.
    return results;
}

/** Load TF Lite model from assets. */
private static MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(AssetManager assetManager, String modelPath)
        throws IOException {
    try (AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd(modelPath);
         FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor())) {
        FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
    }
}

/** Load dictionary from model file. */
private void loadLabelFile(InputStream ins) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
    // Each line in the label file is a label.
    while (reader.ready()) {
        labels.add(reader.readLine());
    }
}

/** Load labels from model file. */
private void loadDictionaryFile(InputStream ins) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
    // Each line in the dictionary has two columns.
    // First column is a word, and the second is the index of this word.
    while (reader.ready()) {
        List<String> line = Arrays.asList(reader.readLine().split(" "));
        if (line.size() < 2) {
            continue;
        }
        dic.put(line.get(0), Integer.parseInt(line.get(1)));
    }
}

/** Pre-prosessing: tokenize and map the input words into a float array. */
int[][] tokenizeInputText(String text) {
    Log.d("hello", "tokenize: "+ text);
    int[] tmp = new int[SENTENCE_LEN];
    List<String> array = Arrays.asList(text.split(SIMPLE_SPACE_OR_PUNCTUATION));

    int index = 0;
    // Prepend <START> if it is in vocabulary file.
    if (dic.containsKey(START)) {
        tmp[index++] = dic.get(START);
    }

    for (String word : array) {
        if (index >= SENTENCE_LEN) {
            break;
        }
        tmp[index++] = dic.containsKey(word) ? dic.get(word) : (int) dic.get(UNKNOWN);
    }
    // Padding and wrapping.
    Arrays.fill(tmp, index, SENTENCE_LEN - 1, (int) dic.get(PAD));
    int[][] ans = {tmp};
    return ans;
}

Map<String, Integer> getDic() {
    return this.dic;
}

Interpreter getTflite() {
    return this.tflite;
}

List<String> getLabels() {
    return this.labels;
}
}
```

Comment: Any customization you made in your inference script from the TFLite Reference App? Have you tried to integrate it with TFLite Task Library, which should be compatible with any models created from Model Maker? See the example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/text_classification/android/lib_task_api/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/textclassification/client/TextClassificationClient.java)

Comment: Have you solved it? if yes can you please help me out...